# opening and viewing a file in php

Tags: php, html, file, view

how do i open/view for editing an uploaded file in php?

i have tried this but it doesn't open the file.

```
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'r');
$data = fread($handle,filesize($my_file));
```

i've also tried this but it wont work.

```
$my_file = 'file.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$data = 'This is the data';
fwrite($handle, $data);
```

what i have in mind is like when you want to view an uploaded resume,documents or any other ms office files like .docx,.xls,.pptx and be able to edit them, save and close the said file.

edit: latest tried code...

```
 <?php 
 // Connects to your Database 
 include "configdb.php"; 

 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees") or die(mysql_error()); 
 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 //Outputs the image and other data
 //Echo "<img src=localhost/uploadfile/images".$info['photo'] ."> <br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Name:</b> ".$info['name'] . "<br> "; 
 Echo "<b>Email:</b> ".$info['email'] . " <br>"; 
 Echo "<b>Phone:</b> ".$info['phone'] . " <hr>"; 
 //$file=fopen("uploadfile/images/".$info['photo'],"r+");
 $file=fopen("Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploadfile/images/file.odt","r") or exit("unable to open file");;
 }
 ?>
```

i am getting the error:

```
Warning: fopen(Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploadfile/images/file.odt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploadfile/view.php on line 17
unable to open file
```

the file is in that folder, i don't know it wont find it.

Comment: I wouldn't use SQL for file reading.  What part of your regular fopen doesn't work?  What is the error message?

Comment: Also make sure that (depending on your php version) you don't have open_basedir set in the php.ini - it'll affect what directories are allowed for reading by php. And make sure the path is accurate - watch for possible case-sensitivity. It's either a problem with not being found, or permissions.

Comment: the path is accurate sir..

Answer (score 1):

It might be either:

1. A permissions issue on the server. If it's a linux machine, try `chmod 754 Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploadfile/images/file.odt` (you may need root).
2. An issue with apache (or whatever webserver you might be using). Make sure you've defined a directory entry in the config file for that site. Documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory).

Although, if I recall properly, an odt file will just be binary data rather than the text information. That might be what you're looking for, I don't know. If you just want to read the actual text, and you aren't interested in using some library to extract it, you need to save it as plain text. If you're actually trying to edit these files in the browser, you're gonna need a lot more than just `fopen`.

Comment: its mac. i think its the same with linux right? how do i edit the permission through the terminal?

Comment: @ChristianBurgos same way as linux: chmod

Comment: Mac generally works the same as linux for most stuff in the terminal (with it being BASH and all). That command for editing the permission was meant to be typed into a terminal. If you need root, you need to prepend `sudo` to it.

Answer (score 0):

For text based files you can use [**`file_get_contents`**](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) and [**`file_put_contents`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php)

However, ODT files are zip compressed XML files so you need to decompress them first:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uploadfile/images/file.odt');
if ($res === TRUE) {
  $zip->extractTo('/tmp/myOdt.xml');
  $zip->close();
}

$data = file_get_contents('/tmp/myOdt.xml');

$data .= 'add this to the end';

file_put_contents('path/to/file.txt', $data);
```

---

However, it seems your problem regards the actual path of the file. Try using a relative path instead: `"images/file.odt"`

Comment: is this entirely different from fopen?

Comment: file_get_contents reads text based files, fopen can read binary. Read my updated answer

Comment: is it just the same with microsoft office files?

Comment: No. doc and docx, xls can't be open as txt files. I mean, you can actually open them that way but it would be gibberish. RTF however, can be open as txt